# Solr Ping query caused exception: undefined field text

Tags: search, solr

Im trying to do some work on my server but running into problems. When I try to ping the server through the admin panel I get this error, which I believe might be causing the problem:

> The server encountered an internal error (Ping query caused exception:
>   undefined field text org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Ping query
>   caused exception: undefined field text at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.PingRequestHandler.handleRequestBody(PingRequestHandler.java:76)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
>   at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376) at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:260)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>   at

Can anyone give me a bit of guideance as to what might be going wrong? I'm using Solr 3.6. I think it may be to do with the defined "text" in the schema.xml??

This is my schema currently: https://gist.github.com/3689621

Any help would be much appreciated.

James

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on the error, I am guessing that the query that is defined in the /admin/ping requestHandler is searching against a field named `text`, which you do not have defined in your schema.

Here is a typical ping requestHandler section

```
<requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
  <lst name="invariants">
    <str name="q">solrpingquery</str>
  </lst>
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="qt">standard</str>
    <str name="echoParams">all</str>
    <str name="df">text</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Note how the `<str name="df">text<str>` setting. This is the default field that the ping will execute the search against. You should change this to a field that is defined in your schema, perhaps, `title` or `description` based on your schema.

Comment: Would I be better to add the "text" field to the schema instead?

Comment: No, the ping should be doing something that is relevant to your instance to assert that it is operational. So I would change it to be a field that you know will be in your schema.

Comment: I tried using a 'time' variable in my schema which is of type 'date'. When I tested the ping endpoint I was still getting the exception "Invalid Date String:'solrpingquery'". I am confused as to why that string is being interpreted as a date string. Should I changed 'solrpingquery' to an actual time in my index? I changed it back to the default 'text' and added it back into my schema even though I don't use it. Was the only way I could get this to work for now.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line in your schema.xml

```
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```