# Using Solr with PHP

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, solr

I am trying to use solr with php . I have configured my solr application and it's working fine . However I am not able to communicate with solr using php . I have tried a number of extensions : pecl-solr , solr-php-client and Solarium . However none were able to even ping my solr server . All this while my solr server is available at localhost:8080/solr . I am running it on windows with tomcat . (I have checked my tomcat and solr services all the while when pinging through php , they were up and running )

I think I am doing something very basic wrong here . Does my solr application need to be in htdocs in xampp ? Because I have it inside the webapps folder of my tomcat server . I dont really see how it could make a difference since I specifically provided the path to ping in solr-php-client like this :

```
 require_once( 'Apache/Solr/service.php' );


 $solr = new Apache_Solr_Service( 'localhost', '8080', '/solr' );
  var_dump($solr) ; 
  if ( ! $solr->ping() ) {
     echo 'Solr service not responding.';
      exit;
    }
```

I get the 'Solr service not responding' message on running this code . Any suggestions ?

Update : I was looking under the hood and found that for getting the contents , the following php function is used : file_get_contents
I further came to know that when the file is located through a URI it may fail as many servers block this command because of security concerns . Is this true for xampp as well ? Running on my local machine that is ?

Comment: Windows. I think it might be related to this question however : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350606/solr-ping-query-caused-exception-undefined-field-text
as I just observed that an error is thrown when I try the following : localhost:8080/solr/admin/ping . Some problem with the request handler it seems

Comment: Try with the inbuilt `curl` HTTP client for PHP; which may need to be enabled depending on your setup. Does that work?

Comment: I have curl enabled . However I am not well versed with it . Can you suggest some piece of code to use and test things out using curl ?

Comment: I managed to work out responses using curl . Please refer to my edit for the issue . Also is there a way to get curl response as an xml rather than as a long string ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope it'll helpful to you, & its working for me.

```
$solr = new Apache_Solr_Service( 'localhost', '8080', '/solr' );
  var_dump($solr) ; 
  if ( $solr->ping() ) {
     echo 'Solr Server Responding.';
      // your code
    }else{
      echo "Solr Server is not Running";
    }
```

from your code just remove `require_once( 'Apache/Solr/service.php' );` this.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to ping your solr server because of you not mentioned the your core name.

```
require_once('Apache/Solr/Service.php');
$solr = new Apache_Solr_Service( 'localhost', '8080', '/solr/CORE_NAME' 
 );
var_dump($solr) ;
if ( ! $solr->ping() ) {
 echo 'Solr service not responding.';
  exit;
}
```

You just have to add core name

```
$solr = new Apache_Solr_Service( 'localhost', '8080', '/solr/CORE_NAME');
```

Once you pass core name created by you it will started working for you.